# Compass style libraries for LESS css?

Tags: css, less, compass-sass

SASS has Compass (a community maintained library of sass mixins/methods).

Does LESS have any supporting libraries that can compare to Compass? Listing anything would be helpful!

Comment: if we make one, we can't call it Less Framework.
I started one called LessLib: https://github.com/dancrew32/lesslib
If you happen to visit this page looking for answers, feel free to contribute!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Another great mini-library...

**Bootstrap**
by Mark Otto, Designer at Twitter

> Bootstrap is a super awesome pack of
>   mixins and variables to be used in
>   conjunction with LESS, a CSS
>   preprocessor for faster and easier web
>   development.

Demo/Site: http://getbootstrap.com/

Mixins: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less/mixins

Github/Source: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Comment: The color variables are a good idea, but they seem to be a little more implementation specific, rather than framework material. However, I really like the grid system and completeness of the gradient mix-ins found in this one. Thank you for contributing, Chris!

Comment: just to keep this up to date, the new github source is https://github.com/markdotto/Preboot.less

Comment: They seem to have moved once more, this time graduating to an official Twitter project. :) I've updated the answer.

Comment: The site does not list all the mixins if you want to use the LESS source directly. However they're easily found in the source in a [`less/mixins.less`](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less) file.

Comment: Actually it's *only* the mixins that compare to compass, no? And I wouldn't consider Bootstrap mini.

Answer (score 20):

There are [less elements](http://lesselements.com), but it's hardly a collection. I agree it would be nice to have something like this.

Comment: thank you for contributing to this discussion! Every mini-library out there will help! I feel like a lot of people are searching for this stuff but not finding anything about it.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at my [compless](https://github.com/neoascetic/compless) repo. There I try to implement some features of Compass using less. Mixins are divided into categories in a way how it done in Compass' [reference](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/). Patches are welcome! :)

Answer (score 6):

Here are another couple of choices: [**lesshat**](http://lesshat.com/) and [**clearless**](http://clearleft.github.com/clearless/)

Also, [this blog post](http://designshack.net/articles/css/battle-of-the-less-mixin-libraries-less-elements-vs-less-hat-vs-bootstrap/) compares 3 less libraries: **less elements** vs **bootstrap** vs **lesshat**.

From the post, it seems like both bootstrap and lesshat beat less elements,

however depending what you need you would choose between bootstrap and lesshat.

> Bottom line, if you’re looking to completely redefine and systematize
>   the way that you build websites, check out Bootstrap. However, if
>   you’re just a LESS user looking for some mixins, I definitely
>   recommend checking out LESS Hat.

**PS:**

If you're just look looking for some basic mixins, and for you - a whole library is overkill - then maybe [this post from css-ticks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/useful-css3-less-mixins/) is more for you.

Answer (score 2):

I just launched {lessins}, it is a library of common mixins, similar to bootstrap.less or less elements, but with a focus exclusively on mixins (the others include some unecessary variables, that seem remnants of other projects.)

I have also organized the mixins into bundles. Check it out: https://github.com/jdmiller82/-lessins-

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but right now [Lots of Love for Less](http://mateuszkocz.github.com/3l/) (3L) is far more complete and generic than Preboot née Bootstrap!

Comment: will check it out! the mobile site is totally unusable on iPhone 4S!

Comment: Haha, yeah, it doesn't come with a grid or responsive classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Preboot](http://markdotto.com/bootstrap/). It is a pretty cool LESS library from a member of Bootstrap team.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but let me share this recently made [Bootstrap3-LESSHAT Boilerplate](https://github.com/ajnaidas/Bootstrap-3-LESSHat-FontAwesome-Boilerplate).

The Boilerplate has the LESS Hat Mixin Library (counterpart of Compass) set up as well as the Font Awesome Iconset.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new library called [more-or-less](https://github.com/pixelass/more-or-less) which is similar [lesshat](http://lesshat.madebysource.com/) but a lot faster since it does not use inline-javascript.
Just like lesshat it allows to use endless layers for e.g `box-shadow` or `background-image`.
It basically has all of the lesshat mixins plus a few other helpful functions.

- `.for()`
- `.find()`
- `.in()`
- `.join()`
- `.repeat()`

> requires Less 1.7.0 or later